# HTML5 Audio Player Stop and Pause Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I got the play button to play and the volume up and volume down button work but the pause button and the stop button aren't working. Also it doesn't work in Chrome, but works in Firefox and Internet Explorer. So How can I fix this too? Thanks.

Here's my code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
    <title>app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="music.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        var player;
        var intv;
        var slider;

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('btnPlay').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            document.getElementById('btnPause').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            document.getElementById('btnStop').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            document.getElementById('btnVolUp').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            document.getElementById('btnVolDown').addEventListener('click', playMusic, false);
            player = document.getElementById('player');
            slider = document.getElementById('sliderTime');
            slider.addEventListener('change', reposition, false);
            getMusicList();
        }

        function reposition() {
            player.currentTime = slider.value;
        }

        function volUp() {
            if (player.volume < 1) {
                player.volume += 0.1;
                console.log(player.volume);
            } else {
                player.volume = 1;
            }
        }

        function volDown() {
            if (player.volume > 0) {
                player.volume -= 0.1;
                console.log(player.volume);
            } else {
                player.volume = 0;
            }
        }

        function playMusic() {
            player.play();
            intv = setInterval(update, 100);
            slider.max = player.duration;
        }

        function update() {
            document.getElementById('songTime').innerHTML = millisToMins(player.currentTime);
            slider.value = player.currentTime;
        }

        function pauseMusic() {
            player.pause();
            clearInterval(intv);
        }

        function millisToMins(seconds) {
            var numminutes = Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
            var numseconds = (((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
            if (numseconds >= 10) {
                return "Time Elapsed:" + numminutes + ":" + Math.round(numseconds);
            } else {
                return "Time Elapsed: " + numminutes + ":0" + Math.round(numseconds);
            }
        }

        function stopMusic() {
            player.plause();
            player.currentTime = 0;
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }

        function getMusicList() {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
            var elementsArray = xmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('composition');
            var arrayLength = elementsArray.length;
            var output = "<table>";
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                var title = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[o].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var composer = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('composer')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var time = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('time')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var fileName = elementsArray[i].getElementsByTagName('filename')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                output += "<tr>";
                output += ("<td onclick='songSelect(\"" + fileName + "\")'>" + title + " By: " + composer + "</td>");
                output += "</tr>"

            }
            output += "</table>";
            document.getElementById('musicList').innerHTML = output;
        }

        function songSelect(fn) {
            document.getElementById('player').src = fn;
            playMusic();
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #musicList td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 3px;
        }
        #musicList td:hover {
            background-color: #990000;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="content1">
        <div id="audioPlayer">
            <audio id="player">
                <source src="sleepAway.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                    <source src="sleepAway.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            </audio>
            <button onclick="playMusic()" id="btnPlay">Play</button>
            <button onclick="pauseMusic()" id="btnPause">Pause</button>
            <button onclick="stopMusic()" id="btnStop">Stop</button>
            <button onclick="volUp()" id="btnVolUp">Volume Up</button>
            <button onclick="volDown()" id="btnVolDown">Volume Down</button>
            <span id="songTime"></span>

            <input id="sliderTime" type="range" min="0" value="0" />
            <div id="musicList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

music.js

```
var xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
xml +='<music>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +=' <title>O Mio Babbino Caro</title>';
xml +=' <composer>Puccini</composer>';
xml +=' <time>2:12</time>';
xml +=' <filename>SleepAway.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +=' <title>2:57</time>';
xml +=' <filename>gershwin.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +=' <title>The Man I Love</title>';
xml +=' <composer>Gershwin</composer>';
xml +=' <time>2:57</time>';
xml +=' <filename>gershwin.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +=' <title>2:57</time>';
xml +=' <filename>gershwin.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
xml +=' <titleAllegro</title>';
xml +=' <composer>Beethoven</composer>';
xml +=' <time>3:45</time>';
xml +=' <filename>piano.mp3</filename>';
xml +=' </composition>';
xml +=' <composition>';
```

Answer (score 0):

All your event listeners point to: "playMusic" so they all act as play buttons.

Comment: Thank You. I missed that. Would you be able to tell me why it doesn't work in chrome?